# Build colour gradation into html

Tags: html, css

This is the top row (banner) on my website:

```
#toprow {position: static;top:0px}
```

I have found the following code, which I believe will enable me to grade the color from dark blue to light blue. Despite many attempts, I have yet to find a way to build it into my banner:

```
#grad
{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(0,102,255), rgb(153,204,255)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(0,102,255), rgb(153,204,255)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(0,102,255), rgb(153,204,255)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(rgb(0,102,255), rgb(153,204,255)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Comment: try messing around here to get the effect you want : http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: The ID in your CSS has to match the ID in your HTML.

Comment: The code you posted is a set of CSS rules. You just need to apply those rules to your element. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Thanks. I've been messing around. - trying to apply the css to the element - in all sorts of ways without success.

Comment: What is the ID of the object you want to have a gradient? Is it "grad"?

Comment: grad is what does the color gradation. One of the things I want to apply it to is this:#ftr{
 margin-top:10px; 
 font-size: 10px; 
 font-weight: normal; 
 font-variant: normal; 
 background-color: #5688c7;
 text-align : center ; 
 padding-bottom : 0px ; 
 color : #FFFFFF ;
 width:100%;
 position:absolute
}

Comment: "The code you posted is a set of CSS rules. You just need to apply those rules to your element. What exactly is the issue?" The issue is how do I apply the rules to the element? I've been trying various ways without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), you can easily achieve what you want. This will give you cross browsers solution also. See below for your colour gradation given by colorzilla:

```
background: #0066ff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0066ff 0%, #99ccff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0066ff), color-    stop(100%,#99ccff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #0066ff 0%,#99ccff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #0066ff 0%,#99ccff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #0066ff 0%,#99ccff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #0066ff 0%,#99ccff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0066ff', endColorstr='#99ccff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Now, if you place this code in `#grad` it suppose that you have an HTML element having `id="grad"`.